# Understanding Neo4j index usage for fast data ingestion regardless of DB size

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am attempting to build a Neo4j ingestion framework for a psudo real-time event pipeline. Every event is assigned a UUID4 before ingest, and it is this UUID4 field that is used in a uniqueness constraint on the label :Entity. All events are given the label :Entity along with their other relevant labels. Any ingest to Neo4j is prefixed with a merge on this UUID field to create the node/edge if it does not exist but prevent creation of duplicate events. It is my current understanding that this uniqueness constraint should allow for matches (via merge) on this UUID field at a speed that is invariant to the number of nodes/edges already in neo4j due to the INDEX created on the field.

Unfortunately, that is not the result I am seeing in testing. As the number of nodes/edges in neo4j increases, the rate of ingestion slows proportionally.

Am I incorrectly using the Neo4j INDEX in my goal for a consistently fast ingest? Or do I just misunderstand the Neo4j INDEX in general?

Any insight into this issue is much appreciated!

For reference, this is the general form of the ingest queries:

```
     UNWIND [...] as params
     WITH params.meta as meta, params.props as props
     MERGE (a :Entity {unique_id: meta.unique_id})
     SET a += props
```

The UNWIND is used to preform a bulk ingest of multiple events in one transaction.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of a Profile

[image]

Comment: Can you PROFILE your query and add a screenshot of the plan, after expanding all plan elements?

Comment: Sure! This is exactly why I'm so confused. It looks like the index is being used but the slowdown occurs anyway.

Comment: The plan looks fine, so it may be an issue with the volume of data you're processing at once. What sizes are you using for the input collections?

Comment: I've tried a bunch of sizes between 10 and 10,000. All have the linear-ish slowdown as the data size of neo4j increases

Comment: A thought: could it be related to the amount of available heap space for the index? And when it runs out neo4j starts swapping?

Comment: Possibly. How much memory is available, and what are your heap and pagecache settings in neo4j.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that increasing the page-cache size solved the problem. I believe I was swapping data to disk.